# onclick via button using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick

Using foreach I displayed entries with two buttons along with it - update and delete respectively, how to make those  buttons responsive using onclick(php or javascript)? [Please click here to view attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aR6b.png). Thanks.

note: the unlabelled buttons are along the entries - rightmost
Here's the code:

```
$get_product_details = $db->query("SELECT product_name,product_type FROM products WHERE product_code = '$product_code'");
foreach($get_product_details as $key) {
    echo'<tr><td>'.$key['product_name'].'</td><td>'.$key['product_type'].'</td><td><input type =  "text" name = "actual_case" value = "'.$quantity.'"class = "form-control" style = "width:20%;"></td>
    <td><a href="?update='.$product_code.'"<input type = "button" name = "update" class =  "form-control" value ="update" style = "width:20%;height:0"></a></td>
    <td><a href="?remove='.$product_code.'"<input type = "button" name = "remove" id = "" class =  "form-control" value ="remove" style = "width:20%;height:0"></a></td></td></tr></br>';
}
if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
    $delete_entry = $db->query("DELETE * FROM order_supplier_list WHERE order_supplier_id = '$transaction_id' AND product_code = '".$_GET['remove']."'");   
}
if(isset($_GET['update'])){
    $qntity = $_POST['actual_case'];
    $update_order = $db->query("UPDATE order_supplier_list SET quantity = '$qntity' WHERE order_supplier_id = '$transaction_id' AND product_code = '".$_GET['update']."'");
}
```

Comment: I can't see how the DELETE would possibly work here. If you're still using that, it's failing on you.

Comment: ^ am I blowing bubbles again? *"Yes Fred, you are."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created a hidden field to hold the value of the $product_code variable and took away the anchor tags since i took care of that in ajax.
i then get this value in jquery,build the url with it in the ajax section.

```
foreach($get_product_details as $key) {
  echo'<tr><td>'.$key['product_name'].'</td>  <td>'.$key['product_type'].'</td><td><input type =  "text" name = "actual_case" value = "'.$quantity.'"class = "form-control" id="quantity" style = "width:20%;"></td>
  <td><input type = "hidden" name = "product_code" class =  "form-control" value ="'.$product_code.'" style = "width:20%;height:50"></td>
 <td><input type = "button" name = "update" class =  "form-control" value ="update" style = "width:20%;height:50" onclick="updateProduct()"> </td>
    <td><input type = "button" name = "remove" id = "" class =  "form-control" value ="remove" style = "width:20%;height:50" onclick="deleteProduct()></td></td></tr></br>';}
```

this part is the jquery with ajax part

```
$(function(){


function updateProduct(){
    var hiddenProduct_Code=$('#hiddenProduct_code').val();
    var quantity=$('#quantity').val();
    $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "?update="+hiddenProduct_Code+"",
            data: {'update' : hiddenProduct_Code,'actual_case':quantity},
            success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
               alert(data);
            }
        },
    });
}

function deleteProduct(){
    var hiddenProduct_Code=$('#hiddenProduct_code').val();
    $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: "?remove="+hiddenProduct_Code+"",
            data: {'remove' : hiddenProduct_Code},
            success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
               alert(data);
            }
        },
    });
}
});
```

you can perform the needed task move to the page where you check whether an update or delete action was triggered

```
    <?php 


if(isset($_GET['remove'])){
    $delete_entry = $db->query("DELETE  FROM order_supplier_list WHERE order_supplier_id = '$transaction_id' AND product_code = '".$_GET['remove']."'");   
}
if(isset($_GET['update'])){
    $qntity = $_GET['actual_case']; //I change it from $_POST to ensure uniformity
    $update_order = $db->query("UPDATE order_supplier_list SET quantity = '$qntity' WHERE order_supplier_id = '$transaction_id' AND product_code = '".$_GET['update']."'");
}

 ?>
```

hope this helps
DELETE syntax was fixed you can find out more from 
 [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) thanks to @Fred

Comment: Thank you for your response **Sir SBA**, but my primary concern is how to make an onclick function having  delete and update sql query which are can be executed just by clicking a button. Since I have two different sql queries(delete and update query) there are two buttons as well with its corresponding onclick function.

Comment: @Count Dracula in that case using ajax to handle either update or remove action based on which button is clicked is the way out. Pls let me know if this what you want to achieve

Comment: Exactly **Sir SBA**,that is what I wanted to accomplished. I hope you can help me on this.

Comment: I can't see how the DELETE would possibly work here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is  just section of the de code that was posted so i think values like $transaction_id are already in the scripts and can be used to create session values so it can be used anywhere in the project. For delete $_GET['remove'] is from the ajax data{ 'key' : value } pair

Comment: I'm talking about `DELETE *` - That is invalid syntax. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html - if you knew MySQL/SQL (I don't know if you do or not), but if you did know the syntax, you could have adjusted your answer to reflect the syntax error.

Comment: You're welcome, and I noticed the edit, good... yet you need to "write it out" also, stating the syntax was incorrect and using the reference link I gave you. It helps for future readers as well; just a quick pro tip for you ;-)